# Why is the command called which and not where?

Tags: shell, command, history

Why is the command called `which` and not `where`?

Logically, you would want to search for the location of the executables, hence "where" are they, but not which.

Comment: Why would you want to search for the location of an executable and not know which of the installed versions of an executable would be called? The location of an executable, if there's only one, is unimportant. If there are several, you want to know which of them would be called, wouldn't you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: There is a `whence` command in Korn shells ;-).

Comment: it is not a search for an executable ... it does not return multiple possibilities

Comment: @jsotola it doesn’t by default but it can — `which -a`.

Comment: Of course I tried searching for the answer myself beforehand, but the post you provided doesn't answer the etymology of the naming at all @they

Comment: You can easily find the etymology and origins of the naming of the "recorder", which would contain at least some sort of explanation, which is not as easy with the "which" command. That's exactly why I asked the question and put a history tag on it - maybe somebody knows, @zevzek

Comment: Perhaps it's because I've been using *nix since forever - but `which` makes perfect sense to me for the reasons outlined in the first comment - sure, I may want to know where a certain command is, but more importantly, I want to know which command is run if I type `xyzzy` - since that name could exist in multiple locations in my PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The etymology is given in [an early version of the `which` program](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-3/usr/ucb/which):

> which : tells you which program you get

Only Bill Joy could tell you why the question was “which program do I get” rather than “where does the program come from” (but note that asking “where” ends up assuming there’s only one, when the purpose of `which` was to determine which program would be used out of a potential set of programs).

Answer (score 2):

This was mostly covered in comments, but this is my take on it.

The reason I have always understood it is that `which` is showing you **which** binary is being called; there may be multiple binaries with the same name, but only one will be chosen when you run the command.

`which` determines which of these binaries is being run by traversing the `$PATH` environment variable:

```
[root@headdesk ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
[root@headdesk ~]#
```

`which` is going to look in `/usr/local/sbin`, then `/sbin`, and so on.

For example, look at `which vim`, which is found in the 3rd position of our `$PATH`:

```
[root@headdesk ~]# which vim
/bin/vim
```

If we add an executable with a higher path precedence, we will see the executable we added:

```
[root@headdesk ~]# >/usr/local/sbin/vim; chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/vim
[root@headdesk ~]# which vim
/usr/local/sbin/vim
```

If we want to see all `vim` executables in our path, we can use the `-a` flag:
[root@headdesk ~]# which -a vim
/bin/vim
/usr/bin/vim

This is covered more concisely in the man page:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been
> executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt. It
> does this by searching for an executable or script in the directories
> listed in the environment variable PATH using the same algorithm as
> bash(1).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the two excellent answers by cutrightjm and Stephen Kitt, there is a `whereis` command which does what you say.

From its manpage:

```
whereis - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```